# How can I get the projections for specific category in Event Store?

Tags: eventstoredb

I made following projection in Event Store:

```
fromCategory('Ping')
.foreachStream()
.when({
   $init: function() { 
     return { 
       min: 0,
       max: 0,
       sum: 0,
       cnt: 0
    }; 
   },
   $any: function(s, e) {
      if (s.max < e.body.AcPower) {
        s.max = e.body.AcPower;
      }
      if (s.min > e.body.AcPower) {
        s.min = e.body.AcPower;
      }
      s.sum += e.body.AcPower;
      s.cnt += 1;
      s.avg = s.sum/s.cnt;
   }
});
```

How can I get the result for a specific stream?
The stream Ids are: "Ping-255.1", "Ping-255.2".... "Ping-255.1000"

Looking at:
http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont
i get:

```
{
  "coreProcessingTime": 4072,
  "version": 0,
  "epoch": -1,
  "effectiveName": "stats-cont",
  "writesInProgress": 0,
  "readsInProgress": 0,
  "partitionsCached": 1000,
  "status": "Running",
  "stateReason": "",
  "name": "stats-cont",
  "mode": "Continuous",
  "position": "$ce-Ping: 132233",
  "progress": 100.0,
  "lastCheckpoint": "$ce-Ping: 131999",
  "eventsProcessedAfterRestart": 132234,
  "statusUrl": "http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont",
  "stateUrl": "http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont/state",
  "resultUrl": "http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont/result",
  "queryUrl": "http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont/query%3Fconfig=yes",
  "enableCommandUrl": "http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont/command/enable",
  "disableCommandUrl": "http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont/command/disable",
  "checkpointStatus": "",
  "bufferedEvents": 0,
  "writePendingEventsBeforeCheckpoint": 0,
  "writePendingEventsAfterCheckpoint": 0
}
```

The following is not working:
http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont/state?partition=255.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In event store 4.0 and later, enable the by category built in projection:

```
curl "http://localhost:2113/projection/$by_category/command/enable" -X POST -H "Content-Length: 0" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Y2hhbmdlaXQ="
```

The Authorization header in this example contains the default admin:changeit credentials.

When the by category projection is enabled, a $ce-Ping stream is created for the Ping-* events. View the $ce-Ping stream using this URL:

http://127.0.0.1:2113/web/index.html#/streams/$ce-Ping

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by debugging Event-store :-).

The partition is actually with category ("Ping-255.1") so the real URL to get the state projection state is:
http://localhost:2113/projection/stats-cont/state?partition=Ping-255.1

Comment: Thanks. I was referring to this post: http://codeofrob.com/entries/creating-a-projection-per-stream-in-the-eventstore.html. Guess it's a bit old.

Comment: I spent a day looking for this... ES is awesome but it's documentation is a complete mistake.